# Expressing Redis Time Complexity

Tags: types, casting, redis, type-conversion, time-complexity

The time complexity of Redis' HDEL is O(N) (where N is the number of fields to be removed). I have a use case where the field must undergo a type conversion for every operation. How would I express the new time complexity? O(N*2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time complexity will be the same: O(N). Big-O notation is not about clock time, but about scalability. See [here](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/12/07/comp-sci-101-big-o-notation/) for an excellent and easy overview.

Answer (score 1):

Complexity will still be `O(n)`.

Take this example:
Algorithm to traversing a linked list of size 'n' is `O(n)`. Traversing it twice is still `O(n)`. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation to difference between O notation and Θ notation.